# Throwed $N$ nuts

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

One player throws $N$ nuts, with $N\sim Geo(\frac{1}{2})\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(N=n)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}=\frac{1}{2^n}$. Let $S_i$ the result of the i-th throwing and $S=\sum_{i=1}^{N}S_i$. Find:

1. $\mathbb{P}(N=2|S=4)$

$\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(N=2|S=4)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(N=2,S=4)}{\mathbb{P}(S=4)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(N=2)\mathbb{P}(S=4,N=2)}{\mathbb{P}(S=4,N=2)+\mathbb{P}(S=4,N=3)+\mathbb{P}(S=4,N=4)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(N=2)\mathbb{P}(S=4|N=2)}{\mathbb{P}(N=2)\mathbb{P}(S=4|N=2)+\mathbb{P}(N=3)\mathbb{P}(S=4|N=3)+\mathbb{P}(N=4)\mathbb{P}(S=4|N=4)}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{13}}{\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{8}\cdot \frac{1}{72}+\frac{1}{16}\cdot \frac{1}{1296}}$

where the combinations for $\mathbb{P}(S=4|N=2)$ are (3,1),(2,2),(1,3), the combinations for $\mathbb{P}(S=4|N=3)$ are (1,1,2),(1,2,1),(2,1,1) and the combination for $\mathbb{P}(S=4,N=4)$ is (1,1,1,1).

2. $\mathbb{P}(N$ even$)$

I thought to write $\mathbb{P}(N$ even$)=\mathbb{P}(N$ even$|S$ even$)+\mathbb{P}(N$ even$|S$ odd$)$ but I don't understand how to calculate these probabilities.

3. $\mathbb{P}(S=4|N$ even$)$
4. $\mathbb{P}(N=2|S=4,S_1=1)$
   $\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(N=2|S=4,S_1=1)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(N=2)\mathbb{P}(S=4,S_1=1|N=2)}{\mathbb{P}(N=2)\mathbb{P}(S=4,S_1=1|N=2)+\mathbb{P}(N=3)\mathbb{P}(S=4,S_1=1|N=3)+\mathbb{P}(N=4)\mathbb{P}(S=4,S_1=1|N=4)}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{36}}{\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{8}\cdot \frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{16}\cdot \frac{1}{1296}}$
   where the combination for $\mathbb{P}(S=4,S_1=1|N=2)$ is (1,3), the combinations for $\mathbb{P}(S=4,S_1=1|N=3)$ are (1,2,1),(1,1,2) and the combination for $\mathbb{P}(S=4,S_1=1|N=4)$ is (1,1,1,1).

---

Hoping that points 1) and 4) are correct, can you help me with the remaining two points? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't get how $S_i$ is defined. What are the possible results?

Comment: @YJT Good question… This is the text: nothing else. We don't have the solutions (Thanks to the professor).

Comment: As far as I know, nuts are something you eat, not something you throw :D One must have a precise definition of $S_i$ and $S$ to solve it.
BTW: $\Pr(N even)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 0.5^{2k}$

Comment: @YJT Context Reverso docet :D Dices is better? By the way, we don't have a definition of $S_i$.